# Asp.net MVC Entity Synchronize table data to another table using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

thank you for taking your time to read my problem. I have been trying to build an asp.net MVC application for a project I have to do that requires me to make a simple online bank application.

I have spent hours wrapping my head around trying to synchronize two entity framework database tables together. I'm not sure if I'm taking the correct approach so I created one table AccountsUser that handles registration and login and another CurrentAccount that has Id, AccountNumber and balance. My approach was to synchronize Id from AccountsUser with foreign key and to auto increment AccountNumber with a seed value.

I already have Entity Framework and have used it to create a Model Class. I have browsed for hours looking at synchronization, table mapping, foreign keys, indexing and even inputting raw SQL statements into my controller.
Here is a breakdown. I know I'm missing a lot of validation etc but its one module not a final project it doesn't need to be to complicated. All the features I'm posting below do work

**Controller**

```
public class AccountsController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(AccountUser Account, CurrentAccount AccountType)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (AccountsDbEntities db = new AccountsDbEntities())
            {
                db.AccountUsers.Add(Account);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            ModelState.Clear();

            ViewBag.Msg = "Welcome " + Account.FirstName + " Your account     has been successfully created";
        }
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(AccountUser user)
    {
        using (AccountsDbEntities db = new AccountsDbEntities())
        {
            var usr = db.AccountUsers.Single(u => u.UserName == user.UserName && u.Password == user.Password && u.PIN == user.PIN);

            if (usr != null)
            {
                if (usr != null)
                {
                    Session["Username"] = usr.FirstName;
                    return RedirectToAction("YourAccount", "UserAccount");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorrect Username or     Password.");
                }
            }

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
namespace BankAtm1.Models.DbEntity
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class AccountUser
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required.")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required.")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required.")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required.")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Confirm password doesn't match,         Type again !")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "PIN is required.")]
        [MaxLength(4, ErrorMessage = "PIN Requires 4 Digits.")]
        [MinLength(4, ErrorMessage = "PIN Requires 4 Digits.")]
        public string PIN { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So to keep my problem short I would like to register user on AccountUser and sync Id onto CurrentAccount then it will hopefully populate AccountNumber. Feel free to rip my approach apart as I am new to MVC and would like to learn it so I just need a push in the right direction with this. Any advice greatly appreciated. Thanks. [Here is my Entity Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6y8DO.jpg)

I managed to do it, **here is my solution.**

```
public ActionResult Register(AccountUser Account)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (AccountsDbEntities db = new AccountsDbEntities())
        {
            db.AccountUsers.Add(Account);
            db.SaveChanges();

            //Populates CurrentAccountId
            int CurrentId = Account.Id;
            CurrentAccount ca = new CurrentAccount();
            ca.Id = CurrentId;
            db.CurrentAccounts.Add(ca);
            db.SaveChanges();

            //Populates SaverAccountId
            int SaverId = Account.Id;
            SaverAccount sa = new SaverAccount();
            sa.Id = SaverId;
            db.SaverAccounts.Add(sa);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        ModelState.Clear();
        //Shows Name

        ViewBag.Msg = "Welcome " + Account.FirstName + " Your account has been successfully created";
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I think db.AccountUsers.Add(Account); populates the Account ID. You should be able to use that data to populate another table (surrentAccount) with the  ID.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Kev your comment helped with a little tweaking. I posted the solution in the question. Not sure if that's what I'm supposed to do but its my first time using this site. Thank.

Comment: Hey Paul, I used this solution in the past and worked well for me. glad i could help